# Table with diagonal line

Tags: tables

Although I have tried to do following table, it didn't work. Could someone  help me how to do this table in LaTeX?

I followed following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l||*{5}{c|}}\hline
\backslashbox{Room}{Date}
&\makebox[3em]{5/31}&\makebox[3em]{6/1}&\makebox[3em]{6/2}
&\makebox[3em]{6/3}&\makebox[3em]{6/4}\\\hline\hline
Meeting Room &&&&&\\\hline
Auditorium &&&&&\\\hline
Seminar Room &&&&&\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

ps: I work in the Texworks.

[image]

Comment: Are you open to alternative suggestions?

Comment: Maybe my problem is: ! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.162 \documentclass
                    {article}

Can you please help me

Comment: @Odko: `l. 162` implies an error around line 162... and that doesn't resemble the minimal example you show.

Comment: this is line 162: \documentclass{article}

Comment: You have 161 lines of comments?  Nothing else should be in front of the \documentclass.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, and some improvements, with `diagbox`(which supersedes `slashbox`), `eqparbox` and `hhline` for nicely intersecting double rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diagbox, eqparbox, hhline}
\setlength{\doublerulesep}{2.5pt}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|l||*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3em}|}}
  \hhline{-||-----}
  \diagbox[width=\dimexpr\eqboxwidth{wd} + 2\tabcolsep\relax, height=0.8cm]{Room}{\raisebox{0.5ex}{Date}}
  & 5/31 & 6/1 & 6/2 & 6/3 & 6/4 \\
  \hhline{=::=====}
  Meeting Room & & & & & \\
  \hhline{-||-----}
  Auditorium & & & & & \\
  \hhline{-||-----}
  \eqmakebox[wd]{Seminar Room} & & & & & \\
  \hhline{-||-----}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]